# Twitter Bootstrap navigation tab with <?php include?> does not work

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a problem with tab navigation. I am not able to display the second and third tab.
Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Dynamic Tabs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#myTab a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#add">Add Employee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sch">Employee List</a></li>
    <li><a href="#list">Employee Schedule</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="add" class="tab-pane active">
        <?php include('addempform.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="sch" class="tab-pane">
        <?php include('addschform.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="list" class="tab-pane">
       <?php include('emplist.php');?>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed the error is with the ?php include('xxx.php')?>. How can i fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @sgt my pages that are supposed to be on the second and third tab won't load.

Answer (score 1):

Hello to put some php code in tab panel  you must insert it between Iframe
like :

```
<iframesrc="xxx.php"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive just corrected your code, jQuery has to be loaded BEFORE bootstrap!

Greetings

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Dynamic Tabs</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#myTab a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#add">Add Employee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sch">Employee List</a></li>
    <li><a href="#list">Employee Schedule</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="add" class="tab-pane active">
        <?php include('addempform.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="sch" class="tab-pane">
        <?php include('addschform.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="list" class="tab-pane">
       <?php include('emplist.php');?>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```